# Gnome Tweak Tool блокирует использование Alt+Shift?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

Добавил через Gnome Tweak Tool изменение раскладки клавиатуры через Shift+Alt

Теперь любые комбинации клавиш связанные с Shift+Alt не работают.

К примеру в VS Code не работает Shift+Alt+UpArrow (для копирования строки вверх) и т.д

Я перешел на Linux с Windows, с виндой работал долго (около 10 лет) из-за этого привык использовать Shift+Alt для смены раслкадки.

Comment: это известная "бага"/особенность гнома.  Она известна много лет и ее не исправляют. Используйте CapsLock - и Ваша жизнь станет прекрасной.

Comment: @KoVadim разве только гнома? у меня на кедах (плазма) аналогичное

Comment: Последний раз я использовал кеды лет 15 назад, если не больше.

Comment: Это проблема X сервера и потому наблюдается во всех DE. Есть какой-то патч который решает эту проблему, но его не принимают в upstream, ведь англоговорящим переключение раскладки не нужно. Самые стойкие его сами накладывают и собирают иксы. Но а я использую дефолтный `Super + Space`.

Comment: попытайся поставить `xorg-hotkeys`, мне на kubuntu + kde plasma (ctrl+shift) помогло